# ActiveRecord column does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I have a Rails app using a Postgres database with a table called geolite_blocks. If I call ActiveRecord like this:

```
GeoliteBlock.find_by_startIpNum 2776360991
```

The query works perfectly. However, if I do the query like this:

```
GeoliteBlock.where("startIpNum >= ?", 2776360991)
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "startipnum" does not exist
LINE 1: ... "geolite_blocks".* FROM "geolite_blocks"  WHERE (startIpNum...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "geolite_blocks".* FROM "geolite_blocks"  WHERE (startIpNum >= 2776360991)
```

But I know that the column exists because I just queried by it with the first code example. Any ideas as to why this might be happening, and how I can eliminate it? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Column names in SQL are case insensitive unless they were quoted when they were created. Someone created your `startIpNum` column with quotes around it so you have to quote it every time you use it:

```
GeoliteBlock.where('"startIpNum" >= ?', 2776360991)
```

The error you're getting from PostgreSQL mentions `startipnum` because PostgreSQL normalizes identifiers to lower case (the SQL standard says that they should be normalized to upper case though).

This:

```
GeoliteBlock.find_by_startIpNum 2776360991
```

works because AR will quote the `startIpNuM` part behind your back. Similarly, `GeoliteBlock.where(:startIpNum => 2776360991)` would also work.

I'd recommend that you change the schema to use lower case column names so that you won't have to worry about this anymore.